# Slick - the prev/next arrow stay stuck inside the sliding carousel

Tags: css

Using slick: http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

HTML

```html
<div class="carsoule" style="overflow:hidden; width: 300px; height: 200px; margin: 0 auto; background:red">
     <div>
          <img src="http://theheightsanimalhospital.com/clients/15389/images/playful-kitten-6683.jpg" width="250">
     </div>
     <div>
          <img src="http://theheightsanimalhospital.com/clients/15389/images/playful-kitten-6683.jpg" width="250">
     </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```css
.slick-prev, .slick-next {
     height: 55px;
     width: 55px;
}
.slick-prev {
     left: -80px;
     /*plan to add button image*/
}
.slick-next {
     right: -80px;
     /*plan to add button image*/
}
```

[Jsfiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vnb1t6ty/1/)

Tried to override, but the prev and next buttons stay stuck inside the carousel. Wanted to replace the css with button images and the buttons should be outside the carousel, just like the example on slick website. Couldn't figure where I went wrong.

Help appreciated!

Comment: Did you try absolute positioning with a higher z-index?

Comment: @SleekGeek - yes I did but nothing works :(. it seems like the buttons are hidden behind the slider

Comment: I don't think there're next and prev in the fiddle html. take a look at it again.

Comment: @SleekGeek: yes it will be added by slick js itself so we dont see next and prev in html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> UPDATE : $('.carsoule').slickNext(); won't work anymore.
>
> Use $('.carsoule').slick("slickNext"); instead.

https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/issues/1613

Looking at the css that this plugin uses, I noticed the parent has `overflow:hidden` applied to it, so your arrows wont show beyond the parents container.

You can mess with adding a extra `overflow !important` rule to the container, however, I've looked over at some methods that you can use to trigger next/prev slide, and turns out that you can call on your carousel to change slide, when clicked on a certain class/id outside of the carousel container.

So basically, after your carousel(or anywhere on the page if it helps you out), add two `div/button/a/whatever` tags, and add either a `class` or id `to` call upon the slider to change its slide using: `slickNext()` or `slickPrev()`

You can wrap everything in a master container, your carousel and those two extra tags and style them the way you want.

Check out the **[demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/c49r1r27/1/)**, and the extra js/markup used bellow:

```
<div class='next-button-slick'>
    next please
</div>
<div class='prev-button-slick'>
    prev please
</div>

$('.next-button-slick').click(function(){
    $('.carsoule').slickNext();
});
$('.prev-button-slick').click(function(){
    $('.carsoule').slickPrev();
});
```

**UPDATE 2**

If you want to keep your markup, and not add any extra stuff, you can either remove the inline overflow: hidden rule from the container, or via css with `overflow: visible !important`, and set those 2 arrows to `position absolute`, and work you way from there.

Check out the **[demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/nu0eoctr/2/)** and the css bellow:

```
/*extra stuff*/
.carsoule{
    overflow: visible !important;
}
.slick-prev, .slick-next {
    position: absolute;
    background: red;
}
```

Comment: thanks but the problem is to position the button between the slide, so i wanted to save time by setting arrows to true and then try to override css

Answer (score 5):

```
<div class='next-button-slick'>
    next please
</div>
<div class='prev-button-slick'>
    prev please
</div>

$('.next-button-slick').click(function(){
    $('#portfolio-carousel').slick("slickNext");
});

$('.prev-button-slick').click(function(){
    $('#portfolio-carousel').slick("slickPrev");
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

This should solve your issue,

CSS

```
body {
    background: #d7d7d7;
}

.carsoule {
    background: yellow;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: visible;
    width: 250px;
}

.slick-prev,
.slick-next {
    height: 55px;
    width: 55px;
}

.slick-prev {
    left: -80px;
    /*plan to add button image*/
}

.slick-next {
    right: -80px;
    /*plan to add button image*/
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="carsoule">
    <div>
        <img src="http://theheightsanimalhospital.com/clients/15389/images/playful-kitten-6683.jpg" width="250" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="http://theheightsanimalhospital.com/clients/15389/images/playful-kitten-6683.jpg" width="250" />
    </div>
</div>
```

The carsoule had overflow:hidden, so if you positioned it outside it was hidden.

Comment: it finally shows buttons, but trying button images, they do not appear at all. :( Perhaps is it because of slick:before with text for arrow?

Comment: I updated my answer, should be what you are looking for.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help. One more qn: any idea why slide isn't showing in IE?

Comment: What version of IE are you using?  I tested IE 9-Edge and it worked fine.

Comment: yeah it is due to legacy ractivejs. So it works for newer IE version 11. thanks again for your help

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the hover. Just add the block of code below to it and you'll be just fine.

```
.slick-next:hover,
.slick-prev:hover {
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
}
```

[**See working example here**](http://jsfiddle.net/nu0eoctr/3/)

Comment: thanks a lot for your help. One more qn: any idea why slide isn't showing in IE?

Answer (score 0):

You missed out the important slick-theme.css http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/slick/slick-theme.css. I added this file and meddled with your codes and came up with this solution:

HTML

Re-styling your wrapper to include .slider class with proper margins:

class="carsoule slider"

Modified CSS

> .slick-prev:before, .slick-next:before {
>         color:red;
>       }
>
> .slick-prev, .slick-next {
>         height: 55px;
>         width: 55px;
>       }
>
> .slick-prev {
>         left: -80px;
>       /*plan to add button image*/
>       }
>
> .slick-next{
>         right: -80px;
>       /*plan to add button image*/
>       }
>
> .slider {
>         margin:0 80px 0 80px;
>         width: auto;
>         }